# how to write Junit test case for testing duplicate elements in List

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

How to write junit test case to test the duplicate value in the userList below mentioned in the code

```
public List<User> getUsersNotInCurrentGroup()
{
List<User> userList = null;
userList = getEntityManager().createQuery("select * from User")

return userList;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." even if it is no homework...

Comment: As a side note: this is not a method whose results should be asserted. The method is just a thin wrapper around `createQuery`. The only thing that can be tested about it is the fact that `createQuery` is called, is called once, and the result of method is same as result of `createQuery`. That is assuming that this method is worth testing at all.

Comment: I am not into those DB frameworks: is `createQuery()` supposed to return a QUERY, or create and execute a query, and return the objects found in the database?

Comment: If your User has suitable equals and hasCode, you can create new HashSet from the list and compare sizes

Comment: Query I have given "select * from user" is place holder. the actual query returns me duplicate values for that I have to write a JUnit test case

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, in this specific case, you should at least know what makes an `User` unique.

Then add a second SQL query with the `distinct` clause and compare if the sizes of both returned collections. It the collections have the same size there are no duplicates.

And would be much easier if you compare the size returned by SQL `count(1)` for each query.

But then this is not a Java Unit test anymore, becomes a kind of DB unit test :)

Comment: Nice idea. I can't help feeling though that really that should be enforced with an index on the table, not unit tested in Java at all.

Comment: @TimB right. What's really wrong is the kind of check this unit test would do.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write a test for duplicates depends on what your application defines as a duplicate.

In Java, every object inherits the method `equals(Object obj)` from the [Object class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). Unless your `User` object overrides that method, no two `User` objects saved in the list will considered equal, because the `equals()` method compares the hash code representing the object and not the values of the data stored in that object.

If you can conceive of ever needing to check whether two `User` objects are the same anywhere else in the application, your best bet would be to override `equals(Object obj)` so that it compares the values your application considers relevant for determining if the two `User` objects are the same.

For example:

```
public class User {
  private int ID;
  private String nickname;
  private String email;

  ...

  @Overrides
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj.getClass() != User.getClass()) {
      return false;
    } else {
      if (obj.getId() == this.getId() && 
          obj.getEmail().equals(this.getEmail()
         ) {

        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

}
```

In this example, the way to determine if one `User` is a duplicate of another, we check whether the ID and email of the two objects are the same, but we don't care if the `nickname` field is different. That determination is purely based on the business need.

Once you have this method in place you can iterate through the list to see if a given object is the same as any of the other objects in the list using the equals() method to compare them.

As a side note, if you are just generally concerned about having a collection without any duplicates, you can use a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) instead of a List, which will call that `equals()` method that you overrode to compare objects for you.